# JqGrid Treegrid doesn't show as a tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf, jqgrid

I'm creating a JqGrid with treegrid view, the jqgrid actually works "as a table", but it doesn't work as a tree
I'll show you mi code below

```
 function doTable1(GridData){
    var json1 = {
        "getAdministrationDataResult": {
            "GridModelData": {
                "page": 0, "records": 0, "rows": [
                    { "ID": "1", "Level": "0", "parent": "", "isLeaf": false, "FreezeId": "0", "Fecha Inicio": "", "Fecha Fin": "", "Area Manager": "AMI", "Team Group": "", "Team": "", "Recurso": "", "Motivo": "", "Activo": "", "Acción": "", "Eliminar": "" },
                    { "ID": "2", "Level": "1", "parent": "0", "isLeaf": true, "FreezeId": "0", "Fecha Inicio": "", "Fecha Fin": "", "Area Manager": "AMI", "Team Group": "Ciclo Pasivo", "Team": "", "Recurso": "", "Motivo": "", "Activo": "", "Acción": "", "Eliminar": "" },
                    { "ID": "3", "Level": "2", "parent": "1", "isLeaf": true, "FreezeId": "0", "Fecha Inicio": "", "Fecha Fin": "", "Area Manager": "AMI", "Team Group": "Ciclo Pasivo", "Team": "Modelo de Costos", "Recurso": "", "Motivo": "", "Activo": "", "Acción": "", "Eliminar": "" },
                    { "ID": "4", "Level": "3", "parent": "2", "isLeaf": true, "FreezeId": "0", "Fecha Inicio": "", "Fecha Fin": "", "Area Manager": "AMI", "Team Group": "Ciclo Pasivo", "Team": "Modelo de Costos", "Recurso": "MUNOZ Oscar", "Motivo": "", "Activo": "", "Acción": "", "Eliminar": "" },
                    { "ID": "5", "Level": "2", "parent": "1", "isLeaf": true, "FreezeId": "0", "Fecha Inicio": "", "Fecha Fin": "", "Area Manager": "AMI", "Team Group": "Ciclo Pasivo", "Team": "SAPCIPA", "Recurso": "", "Motivo": "", "Activo": "", "Acción": "", "Eliminar": "" }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    $("#administration_container").jqGrid('GridUnload');
    $("#administration_container").jqGrid({

        treeGrid: true,
        treeGridModel: "adjacency",
        ExpandColumn: "Level",
        treeDataType: "json",
        colNames: GridData.colNames,
        colModel: GridData.colModel,
        multiselect: false,
        caption: GridData.caption,
        pager: jQuery('#administration_containerPager'),
        rowNum: 1000,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        treeReader : {
            level_field: "level",
            parent_id_field: "parent", // then why does your table use "parent_id"?
            leaf_field: "isLeaf"
        }
    });

    var item;

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        jQuery("#administration_container").jqGrid('addRowData', i, json1.getAdministrationDataResult.GridModelData.rows[0]);
        jQuery("#administration_container").jqGrid('addRowData', i, json1.getAdministrationDataResult.GridModelData.rows[1]);
        jQuery("#administration_container").jqGrid('addRowData', i, json1.getAdministrationDataResult.GridModelData.rows[2]);
        jQuery("#administration_container").jqGrid('addRowData', i, json1.getAdministrationDataResult.GridModelData.rows[3]);
        jQuery("#administration_container").jqGrid('addRowData', i, json1.getAdministrationDataResult.GridModelData.rows[4]);
    }
}
```

Info comes from a wcf vb service, the json i show you, it's just a sample of what the service returns

Need some light on this, thank you and sorry for the sloppy English

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use? You should **never fill the grid using `addRowData` in the loop**. You can use `datastr: addRowData.getAdministrationDataResult.GridModelData` with `datatype: "jsonstring"` or, only for jqGrid, to use `datatype: "local"` with `data: addRowData.getAdministrationDataResult.GridModelData.rows`. Additionally you should fix `"ID"` in input data to `"id"`.

Comment: @Oleg I'm not sure, of what version it is, I'm quite new and I'm repairing this, where can I check? Meanwhile gonna try your changes, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote in the comment to our question that you are the beginner and you are not sure what version you use. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrud. Thus I'd recommend you to download the latest version of the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (just click "download zip" button) or you can use the URLs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit).

The code which create local (from the data already read in the JavaScript object) TreeGrid would be very simple. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTree-fa4-.htm) displays the following TreeGrid

[image]

The corresponding JavaScript code is very easy:

```
var mydata = [
        {id: "10", name: "Cash",        num: 100, debit: 400.00,  credit: 250.00,  balance: 150.00,   enbl: true,
            level: "0", parent: "null", isLeaf: false, expanded: false, loaded: true},
        {id: "20", name: "Cash 1",      num: 1,   debit: 300.00,  credit: 200.00,  balance: 100.00,   enbl: false,
            level: "1", parent: "10",   isLeaf: false, expanded: false, loaded: true},
        {id: "30", name: "Sub Cash 1",  num: 1,   debit: 300.00,  credit: 200.00,  balance: 100.00,   enbl: true,
            level: "2", parent: "20",   isLeaf: true,  expanded: false, loaded: true},
        {id: "40", name: "Cash 2",      num: 2,   debit: 100.00,  credit: 50.00,   balance: 50.00,    enbl: false,
            level: "1", parent: "10",   isLeaf: true,  expanded: false, loaded: true},
        {id: "50", name: "Bank's",      num: 200, debit: 1500.00, credit: 1000.00, balance: 500.00,   enbl: true,
            level: "0", parent: "null", isLeaf: false, expanded: true,  loaded: true},
        {id: "60", name: "Bank 1",      num: 1,   debit: 500.00,  credit: 0.00,    balance: 500.00,   enbl: false,
            level: "1", parent: "50",   isLeaf: true,  expanded: false, loaded: true},
        {id: "70", name: "Bank 2",      num: 2,   debit: 1000.00, credit: 1000.00, balance: 0.00,     enbl: true,
            level: "1", parent: "50",   isLeaf: true,  expanded: false, loaded: true},
        {id: "80", name: "Fixed asset", num: 300, debit: 0.00,    credit: 1000.00, balance: -1000.00, enbl: false,
            level: "0", parent: "null", isLeaf: true,  expanded: false, loaded: true}
    ];

$("#treeGrid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    colNames: ["Account", "Acc Num", "Debit", "Credit", "Balance", "Enabled"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "name", width: 180 },
        {name: "num", template: "integer", align: "center" },
        {name: "debit", template: "number" },
        {name: "credit", template: "number" },
        {name: "balance", template: "number" },
        {name: "enbl", width: 70, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" }
    ],
    cmTemplate: { width: 80, autoResizable: true },
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: "adjacency",
    ExpandColumn: "name",
    ExpandColClick: true
});
```

where the longest part if the code is the initialization of input data which contains properties of different types (integer, decimal and boolean). I used `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8) and some templates which simplifies displaying of the data of the corresponding type.

Comment: Thanks, it worked; if it's useful for someone, I'm having problem pointing my "parent" field, also having trouble with the case sensitive fields, but with this example everything worked perfect.